# How to re-enable introductory onboarding wizard after reinstalling WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I uninstalled my `WooCommerce` plugin and chose to delete all data. When installed it back I cannot see the `Introductory Onboarding Wizard`. I need it to create my shop and all the pages again. I suspect this is because some traces were left from the first installation. How can I re-enable it again?

Comment: Under "WooCommerce -> System Status -> Tools" you can find "Install WooCommerce Pages"

Comment: Life saver! Post this as an answer and I will gladly accept it. This option is not intuitive at all and searching google returns nothing.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the **WooCommerce -> System Status** admin page, under the **Tools** tab, there's the **Create default WooCommerce pages** tool that

> will install all the missing WooCommerce pages. Pages already defined and set up will not be replaced.

Comment: Status -> Tools -> **Create default WooCommerce pages** to create pages

Answer (score 6):

WooCommerce now has a Help tab just to the right of the Screen Options tab in the Wordpress (v4.8) admin panel. Click on the tab and you will discover the Setup Wizard as a selectable item ... among many other helpful goodies ... including a setup video 
[WooCommerce Setup Wizard](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-setup-wizard/)

Comment: This is the right answer to bring back setup wizard! This worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

You can restart setup wizard going to www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/?page=wc-setup. It worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

/wp-admin/?page=wc-setup worked perfectly for me too.

Just login into wordpress and edit this in URL bar. Voila, it works!

Regrads